# Trying to use while loop for range. The range is not printing

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that asks for two inputs between 0 and 100. Then I need to make a while loop to print the range of the inputs and the sum. My while loop does nothing and I'm not sure what to do?

```
while i in range(l,o):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Replace "while" with "for"

Answer (score 1):

`while` is used to run code *while* a boolean is true.
You can use `for` to iterate over a range of numbers.

```
for i in range(l,o):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use `for` loop.

```
for i in range(l,o):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You using `while` instead of `for`

```
for i in range(l,o):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using while instead of for, the code `i in range(1,o)` becomes a boolean. So the condition is if i is in range(1,o). The loop continues if True.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it truly has to be a while loop, you can do it like this:

```py
while l < o:
    print(l)
    l += 1
```

The reason your implementation doesn't work is that `while` is followed by a boolean statement.  So `i in range(l, o)` is evaluated and will either return `True` (in which case your `while` loops runs forever), `False` (in which case our loop never starts), or if `i` is undefined throws an `NameError` exception.